# Running PyCharm Unittests sequentially for packages while running tests within each package in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pycharm, python-unittest

I'm writing unit tests for a published web application. This web application has a variable that changes the functionality of the app and this variable is persistent across all of a user's sessions.

I want to take advantage of running multiple tests in parallel, but I can't have two tests expecting different values for this variable to run at the same time. I'm looking for a way to group tests in bundles to be run in parallel with each bundle having a build-up and tear-down section (used to set the variable to what is expected for the bundle).

I'm using PyCharm Unittest to write all my tests and `-n 6` in `Run Configuration -> Additional Arguments` to run my tests in parallel.

My tests are already broken up into packages based on the state variable's expected value. How do I let Unittest know that I want it to run each of these packages one after another but run tests within a package in parallel?

Folder Structure

```
Tests
  SingleHome
    __init__.py
    test_Entity_CRUD.py
    test_Entity_UI.py
  Apartment
    __init__.py
    test_Entity_CRUD.py
    test_Entity_UI.py
```

Sample File Structure

```
class BaseDriver(unittest.TestCase):

    def _test_load(self, driver):
        driver.get('https://www.google.com')
        self.assertEqual("Google", driver.title)

class ChromeDriver(BaseDriver):

    def test_load(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self._test_load(driver)
        driver.quit()

class EdgeDriver(BaseDriver):

    def test_load(self):
        driver = webdriver.Edge()
        self._test_load(driver)
        driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this using `Run Configuration -> Before launch`.

First I had change my folder structure.

Instead of:

```
Tests
  SingleHome
    __init__.py
    test_Entity_CRUD.py
    test_Entity_UI.py
  Apartment
    __init__.py
    test_Entity_CRUD.py
    test_Entity_UI.py
```

I now have of:

```
Tests Main
Tests SingleHome
  test_Entity_CRUD.py
  test_Entity_UI.py
Tests Apartment
  test_Entity_CRUD.py
  test_Entity_UI.py
```

I set up both run configuration files for `Tests SingleHome` and `Tests Apartment` as I describe in my post (`-n 6`).

And for `Tests Main` I use `Run Configuration -> Before launch` to add both run configuration files `Run Configuration For Tests SingleHome` and `Run Configuration For Tests Apartment`.

Now when I right-click on `Tests Main` and click `Run Tests Main` it'll run in series each of my Run Configurations but run all tests found within in parallel.